# How to check if CONTENT is not empty in TypoScript?

Tags: typoscript

I create a CONTENT object in a following way,

```
   MIDCONTENT = CONTENT
   MIDCONTENT{
       table = tt_content
       select.orderBy = sorting
       select.where = colPos = 0  
   }
```

further i have a TEXT Object, which should get the value test, if MIDCONTENT is not empty

```
   BOTTOMONTENT= TEXT
   BOTTOMONTENT{
       value=test
       if{
          //check here
         }
   }
```

How can i check, if MIDCONTENT, which is a CONTENT object,  is not empty?

Comment: Please answer to your question in "answer" and accept it so this topic will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

do it the other way arround:

```
BOTTOMCONTENT = TEXT
BOTTOMCONTENT.value = test
BOTTOMCONTENT.override.cObject =< MIDCONTENT
```

Comment: Explain:

the stdWrap's override will only load the BOTTOMCONTENT if it returns something else then "" (after trim)

Comment: and where is the check, if MIDCONTENT is not empty?

Comment: somehow it doesnt work - BOTTOMCONTENT always has the value "test" no matter, if MIDCONTENT is empty or not

Comment: the "not empty" check is not needed, because override is just ignored (and keeping therefor the content as is) if override returns something (non empty). Perhaps we missunderstood a bit, because it's a common case for a fallback text "test" if no content is in the BE colomn.

If you really just want to check the emptyness...

    if.isTrue.cObject < MIDCONTENT

could work

Answer (score -1):

```
BOTTOMCONTENT = TEXT
BOTTOMCONTENT.value = midcontent is empty
BOTTOMCONTENT.if.isFalse.cObject < MIDCONTENT
```

Comment: Please give some description to support your answer.

Comment: 1) Load the BOTTOMCONTENT with some value
2) The "if" part tells to render the BOTTOMCONTENT only if the MIDCONTENT is empty. Otherwise BOTTOMCONTENT keeps empty.